# shadow file contains "!" instead of root hash

Tags: linux, john-the-ripper

I'm trying to understand how to crack passwords from `shadow` file and I see the `root` user contains the following content on `/etc/shadow`:

```
root:!:17888:0:99999:7:::
```

What does It mean? How can I crack this password using `john`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `!` indicates that the account has no usable password. You cannot crack it.

This information can be obtained from the documentation installed on your system. See [`man 5 shadow`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shadow.5.html) and search for `!`

Comment: Beat me to it! It's worth noting that `man 5 shadow` explicitly mentions `!`.

Answer (score 0):

Many systems intentionally disable password based login as root. This is what the `!` is for.

To become `root` on these systems one may use `sudo`.